# Pretty Printers for debugging C++ code with Eclipse/CDT in Mac OS

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to accomplish pretty printers (for viewing variables of type vectors,lists etc, STL containers) for debugging C++ using Eclipse (Version: Kepler Service Release 1) and CDT **in Mac OSX Mountain Lion**. I know I can use XCODE to debug, but want to debug using Eclipse. I appreciated any help. Thanks.

I tried the following, but failed debugging:

1. Downloaded GNU gdb from `ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.6.tar.gz`
2. Installed GNU GDB with python the following way

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gdb7.6 --with-python=/usr/bin/python
   make 
   make install
   ```
3. Checked-out the latest Python libstdc++ printers to a folder  ~/gdb_printers

   ```
   svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
   ```
4. Created ~/gdb_printers/.gdbinit and added the following in the .gdbinit file

   ```
   python
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/ravi/gdb_printers/python')
   from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
   register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
   end
   ```
5. Eclipse Setup

In Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Debug > GDB

Where it Says GDB Debugger `/usr/local/gdb7.6/bin/gdb`

Where it says GDB Command File: `/Users/ravi/gdb_printers/.gdbinit`

1. Now, when I try to debug, I get the following error.

   ```
   Error in final launch sequence
       Failed to execute MI command:
       source /Users/ravi/gdb_printers/.gdbinit
   Error message from debugger back end:
   /Users/ravi/gdb_printers/.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:\nError while executing Python code.
   /Users/ravi/gdb_printers/.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:\nError while executing Python code.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Eclipse 4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10.

I'm using the petty printer provided in the package libstdc++6-4.8-gdb in order to have installed the files at /usr/share/gcc-4.8/python

To fix the same message you had I had a look a the code in the printers.py. It happens that the issue was because of the code

```
raise ValueError, "..."
```

that should be writen

```
raise ValueError("...")
```

I don't anything in Python programming but googling around makes me trying this. And it seems to work. Pretty printer is up and running in my Eclipse session.

Hope this helps.
Regards